# Not working var range = sheet.getRange(getstr);

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

GOOGLE DOCS SHEET SCRIPT

```
function sumCellsByColor(color, getstr) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(getstr);
  var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var sum = 0;

  for (var row = 0; row < bgColors.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < bgColors[row].length; col++) {
      if (bgColors[row][col] === color) {
        var cellValue = values[row][col];
        if (typeof cellValue === 'number') {
          sum += cellValue;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return sum;
}
```

**I enter into the cell:
=sumCellsByColor("#ff6d01", "B2:B32")**

it cannot accept a range value..

=sumCellsByColor("#ff6d01", "B2:B32")
=sumCellsByColor("#ff6d01", "sheet1!B2:B32")

Comment: I think that in your showing script, `=sumCellsByColor("#ff6d01", "B2:B32")` can be used. So, can I ask you about the detail of `Not working var range = sheet.getRange(getstr);` and `it cannot accept a range value..`.

Comment: `I enter into the cell: =sumCellsByColor("#ff6d01", "B2:B32")` I used your code and then entered this longhand into the cell (as well as pasting into the formula bar). Works fine. May I ask, you said `it cannot accept a range value..` - how did you come to this comclusion?

Comment: It gives me an error.
Syntax error in the formula. I'm entering everything the same way I sent it here.
maybe I somehow have a script that is not connected to the sheet, or something is not included? Tell me please.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `It gives me an error. Syntax error in the formula. I'm entering everything the same way I sent it here.`, when your showing script is used by putting a custom function of `=sumCellsByColor("#ff6d01", "B2:B32")`, unfortunately, no error occurs. I apologize for this situation. In this case, it is required to correctly replicate your situation. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: `function sumCellsByColor(color, getstr)` Would you please describe where you got this function from.

Comment: I wrote this function myself, I also took some snippets using Google.First of all, in excel google sheet, I select "**Extension - AppsScript**" in the menu. Next, in the editor, I enter the entire function "**function sumCellsByColor(color, getstr) {
...}**" which was provided above. I click save. Then I go to "triggers". I create a trigger for this function "**From the table - When changing**". I'm saving it. Closing Apps Script. And in any free cell I insert "**=sumCellsByColor("#ff6d01", "B2:B32")**". As a result, I get **#ERROR!("Syntax error in the formula.")**.

Comment: But why do I think that this line var range = sheet does not work.getRange(getstr); Because without it (if the range is entered as a variable without input), the color is calmly transmitted and counts the entire amount as it should. ALSO:  
Exception: Argument cannot be null: a1Notation
sumCellsByColor @ 2.gs:3

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm not sure about the reason for using the OnChange trigger. But, in this case, when your function `sumCellsByColor` is run by the OnChange trigger, an error occurs because the event object is not correctly used. I think that this is the reason for your error of `Exception: Argument cannot be null: a1Notation`. And, when I tested your flow, no error occurs at the custom function. I cannot correctly `As a result, I get #ERROR!("Syntax error in the formula.")`. I apologize for this. So, for example, how about confirming the inputted formula again?